# Unable to locate lidar on rviz map through mrpt localization

Tags: localization, mobile-robot-toolkit

I am trying to do localization just using lidar . I uses the map generated by cartographer_ros and do localization using mrpt_localization(http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_localization).

I tried using the command 'roslaunch mrpt_localization demo.launch', it create an existing map from the bag file, similar to 'rosbag play '.

THIS IS THE LAUNCH FILE:

However, after finish the mapping, the lidar location (tf) disappear. I wanted to locate the lidar location in real-time on a generated/existing map. Even after i launch the rplidar_s1.launch it did not work. SEND HELP!!

Comment: Based on https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg/mrpt_navigation.git

Answer (score 0):

The 'roslaunch mrpt_localization demo.launch' launch files already includes a map for demo purposes.

Try making a copy of that launch file, and remove the part that publishes the map (the `demo_rosbag` part). Then, make sure that all the TF and topic names in the `mrpt_localization` section of the launch file matches your settings... without more details on your files, TFs, etc. is hard to give more help, I guess!